# K.K. Slider Bootleg From Other Town?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I know that K.K. Slider gives one bootleg per person, but if a friend from another town came over on Saturday night and requested a song, would he get a bootleg such that he could get one from his town *and* from mine? Or would K.K. Slider just play the song and not give a bootleg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My friend visited my town, requested a song (after I had requested and received a song), and did not receive a copy of the track.  So no.